# On cloud auto image resizing

Tags: php, image, dynamic, resize, cloud

I am at present using cloud file storage powered by Rackspace. We have lots of images which initially we upload to the cloud and later on we download each of the image (after uploaded by users) and convert it into different sizes on server and then uploaded again with predefined naming convention with sizes. like demo.png to demo24x24.png  demo75x75.png demo100x100.png

I am looking for a cloud or cdn based solution which can convert images dynamically. So for example when we should be able to access images with size like these url

cdn.solution.com/demo.png
cdn.solution.com/demo24x24.png
cdn.solution.com/demo75x75.png

Is it possible to implement it using a third party cloud based solution or using any open source solution which works on premise?

Comment: ...you might be heading for a flagged question (recommendations) but I'd have a look at https://www.imgix.com/ if I were you.

Comment: My suggestion is Cloudinary http://cloudinary.com/